# How can I use UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl on a UIView that does NOT take up the whole screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, modal-dialog, transition

In Apple's official Maps app for the iPhone, there is a small 'page curl' button in the lower-right corner.  When you press it, the map itself peels back to reveal some options.  I would like to duplicate this effect in my own app.

I'm trying to use UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl (Added in SDK 3.2).  In terms of its layout, my app resembles Apple's official Maps app almost exactly.  I can easily get the ENTIRE screen to peel back, revealing another view underneath, but I don't want this.  I want ONLY the map view to peel back.

In order to create this effect, you must have a UIViewController that will perform the transition.  If I set this UIViewController's view to a small subview somewhere on the screen that does not take up the entire screen, I can get just that subview to peel back.  That's great!  However, after the second part of the transition (when the page falls back into place), the views are never where they started.  Either the view that peeled back will have moved from its original position, or the view that was revealed will have expanded to take up the entire screen.

Is there any obvious mistake that I'm making?  I would really appreciate any help!

The code I'm using is really simple.  It's basically just:

```
underMapViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;

[curlableMapViewController presentModalViewController:underMapViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Really?  None of the existing answers solved your problem?  [Cough cough cough]  You might want to accept at least 1 one of them, it really helps people to be motivated to help you!

Answer (score 10):

From the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalTransitionStyle):

> `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`
>
> When the view controller is presented, one corner of the current view curls up to reveal the modal view underneath. On dismissal, the curled up page unfurls itself back on top of the modal view. A modal view presented using this transition is itself prevented from presenting any additional modal views.
>
> **This transition style is supported only if the parent view controller is presenting a full-screen view and you use the UIModalPresentationFullScreen modal presentation style**. Attempting to use a different form factor for the parent view or a different presentation style triggers an exception.

Although, I haven't got any exception using other presentations than full screen. I was testing out and I get the same problem as you. I found that if my ParentViewController's view is an ImageView and I set the content mode to UIViewContentModeCenter, the view is not resized or moved. Maybe there is a workaround by saving your current view as an image, put it at the top, make the curl, and after you dismiss your modal, rearrange the messed hidden stuff and remove the top image view. I know that it sounds crazy but that is what I would try if I really had to accomplish that requirement.

Hope this helps, Jorge.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll fool around with the technique you suggested and see if I can come up with something that works.

Answer (score 7):

How about something like this:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"PartialPageCurlEffect" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:myOldSubViewController.view cache:YES];

    [myOldSubViewController.view addSubview:myNewViewController.view];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Note: for some views if the views are complex and off-centre there could be artifacts. Changing `cache:YES` to `cache:NO` may fix with.

Comment: This is a similar effect but not what the OP wanted. This code causes the "old" view to "tear off" completely, rather than just "peel up" a little bit to reveal something underneath (like Maps).

Comment: Reading it again I can understand what he meant. Perhaps one can abort the animation midway somehow to leave it partially revealed?

Answer (score 7):

**As cprcrack points out, this doesn't answer the original question. However, it's useful information, so with that in mind I'm going to leave it here.**

This is actually much simpler than you'd guess.

We'll call the view controllers `MapViewController` and `SettingsViewController`. Your problem is you want to peel back **part** (and only part) of `MapViewController` to show `SettingsViewController`.

Here's how you do it:

- Use a full size view for both views.
- Only put *content* on the *bottom* half of `SettingsViewController`'s view.
- Use `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` to transition between them, like you already are.

iOS will detect that you've done this automatically and only peel `MapViewController`'s view back far enough to the bottom half of `SettingsViewController`'s view, which is where all your content is.

If you put content in the top half of `SettingsViewController`'s view, iOS will detect that and peel back `MapViewController`s view all the way instead.

**Summary: Put content only in the bottom half of your new view. iOS will figure it out.**

(I don't think this is documented anywhere, sorry.)

Comment: Although your answer might be useful, what you are describing is just the normal behavior of `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`. The problem @caecus318 is facing has to due with keeping a bar at the bottom of the view without any animation and going back to the original state.

Comment: Aha, the question never really made sense to me until you explained it. I have amended my answer. (It's useful, so I don't want to just delete it.)

Answer (score 5):

I had a slight hiccough confusing

```
.modalTransitionStyle
```

and

```
.modalPresentationStyle
```

The first one goes on the TARGET viewController, e.g., the one you want underneath. The second goes on the PARENT viewController, e.g. the one that actually gets distorted by the curl. The OP got this right, but I got it wrong, and it was a frustrating 10 minutes before I figured it out. Throwing it on this post in case it gives someone else the head slap I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. For me the frame of the parent view wasn't mangled until the modal view was dismissed. So I cached the frame before dismissing then restored it right after.

```
CGRect frame = controllerWithModal.view.frame;
[controllerWithModal dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
controllerWithModal.view.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Me too had this problem,but i solved it..(dont know its the right way,but its working)

I wanted to had an imageview inside a scrollview,and when the user taps a button inside that scroll view i wanted to curl-up the scroll view and show a tableview in that place.
So i placed a tableview behind scrollview and initialy set it to hidden.when the user taps button 
i did

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:frontView cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

after that removed frontview from view.
Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Apple's Maps application uses undocumented transitions: mapCurl and mapUncurl.  I am not sure there is any way to do exactly what caecus314 wants (which is also the effect I have been trying to duplicate).

UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl will curl up the whole bottom part of the first view, **including** the toolbar, which is **unlike** Apple's Maps app, which only curls up the map and leaves the toolbar in place.

As far as I can tell there is no way to only curl up the map.

Comment: Of course there is a way, in fact the user who asked the question is telling you the procedure to accomplish it. Have you read the question, at least? The part where it says: "I can get just that subview to peel back. That's great!" It's really annoying having to deal with not real answers from people who has not even read the questions carefully. I'm sorry but I had to say it.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `viewWillDisappear` method of your `underMapViewController` with something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    curlableMapViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 416.f);

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

That corrects the size of the view of the `curlableMapViewController` to the know size you specify, which you could save earlier in the `viewWillAppear` method, for example.