# Half Page Curl Effect from the TOP

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am writing an iPhone app but have run into a problem with an animation effect I am trying to implementing.

I am trying to add a half page curl effect from TOP.

I am using CAAnimation of "pageCurl", with the subtype set to kCATransitionFromTop or Right. And I also tried to use UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl of the UIViewController.
But it curls the page from the botton.

My main problem is how to change the transition direction, to get it to curl from the top.

Can anyone help me? I feel that stackoverflow can fix my problem.

Waiting for your replying....
Regards.

Comment: Theres a question on SO about something similar, it may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851914/how-can-i-use-uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-on-a-uiview-that-does-not-take-up

Answer (score 0):

Huh. Just an idea, but what if you tried rotating the view 180 degrees so that its upside-down using a CGAffineTransform (`view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)`) or something? Maybe if the view is upside-down, the animation will also be that way. Its kind of convoluted, and you might need to do a bunch of rotations and reorganizations with subviews to make them positioned correctly and right-side-up oriented, but might work.

Comment: But i turned the view upside down, but the transition doesn't turn upside down.